# Bootstrap - Modal keeps "display: block" when hidden

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I have a bootstrap modal in my web app that keeps being displayed even when I launch `myModal.modal('close');`. I am pretty stuck with that strange problem.

Approx. one in ten times, I have that `display: block;` staying after close. The modal is correctly hidden because I can't see it anymore but it is overlaying my entire page and I cannot click on anything.

I tried to handle the close with :

```
$('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
  $(this).css('display', 'none !important');
})
```

And this does not work, the modal div is still having `style="display: block;"`

Comment: can you create a demo

Comment: `important` does not work with jQuery `.css()`

Comment: you should try to reproduce your issue so we can see it, because, as you said, it is pretty strange

Comment: You might be able to set the z-index way back if its got the right position.  Or try like margin-left or margin-top - 500000 px

Comment: Is `myModal.modal('hide');` not working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try these and let me know if they work.

```
$('selector').css('z-index', '-999');
$('selector').css('margin-left', '-50000');
$('selector').css('margin-top', '-50000');
```

Comment: Yep, worked ! Just forcing `z-index: -999;` on hide and  `z-index: 1000;` on show did the job. But it is still a workaround.

Comment: Sometimes you gotta do what's quickest and move on to  more important things.  :)   Glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

My first question is:  do you have a custom style sheet where you might be overriding the style for #myModal?  If so, work to resolve that.

My second question is:  what version of Bootstrap are you using?  I have seen a bug logged similar to this back in 2012.  If possible, upgrade to the latest version of Bootstrap (3.3.4).

My third question is:  what are you clicking to do the close?  Is it the close button ( type="button" class="close" ) or is it a button with a data-dismiss="modal" attribute?

If the close button, you could try this as long as you don't have other modals on the page:

```
$(".close").on( "click", function() {
    $("#myModal").hide();
});
```

This might be worth a shot, too (though, not the recommended approach):

```
$("#myModal").on("hide",function(){
    $("#myModal").css("display", "none");
});
```

Ultimately, I agree with needing a demo as Amit and Yerko suggest as this seems odd.  I have never run across something like this, and I have used bootstrap for a long while.